# Image Resize NaN Error

Tags: javascript, css, html, image

I am getting NaN back from one of my functions. After doing the research I found out the answer was not a number but I figured that it must be imposable. I am only working with numbers and I am rounding the answer.

```js
 function resize(iid, eid) {
//Get the ID of the elements (ele being the container that the image is in and img being the image its self)
     var img = document.getElementById('img');
     var ele = document.getElementById('contaner');
//makes the var needed
     var currentwidth = ele.clientWidth;
     var currentheight = ele.clientHeight;
     var naturalwidth = img.naturalHeight;
     var naturalheight = img.naturalWidth;
     var newheight = naturalheight;
     var newwidth = naturalwidth;
     var x;
     //runs a loop that should size the image
        while (newheight > currentheight && newwidth > currentwidth){
            x = x + 1;
            newheight = naturalheight / x;
            newwidth = naturalwidth / x;
        }
     newheight = Math.round(newheight);
     newwidth = Math.round(newwidth);
     //alerts out the  answers
     alert(newheight);
     alert(newwidth)
}
```

```css
#contaner {
    height: 450px;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 5% auto;
    position: relative;
}

#img {
    height: 450px;
    width: 90%;
}
```

```html
<div id="contaner">
                <img src = "..\..\Resorces\Images\SlideShow\img1.jpg" style="width:652px;height:489px;" id="img"/>
                <div id="left_holder"><img onClick="slide(-1)" src="..\..\Resorces\Images\arrow_left.png" class="left"/></div>
                <div id="right_holder"><img onClick="slide(+1)" src="..\..\Resorces\Images\arrow_right.png" class="right"/></div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
var x;
```

And then when you do:

```
x = x + 1;
```

`x` is `undefined` it get cast to string and then concatenated with the 1. So:

```
x = 'undefined1';
```

When `x` is used on a division it returns NaN.

Solution: Change `x` declaration:

```
var x = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

**NaN** is due by this line of code:

```
var x;

while (newheight > currentheight && newwidth > currentwidth) {
     x = x + 1; //<- Here x is undefined
}
```